# NURBS and subdivision surfaces

Tags: reference-request, surfaces, spline

I need some links or advices on NURBS, T-Splines, subdivision surfaces and related stuffs. I try to evaluate possibilities for modeling and rendering surfaces (and curves).

Subdivision surfaces and b-splines surfaces are closely related. Relatively to my project, NURBS are useful because they are invariant under projective transformations (common with interactive rendering) and they can represent spheres and other conics without approximation.

<strike>Is there some subdivision surfaces with the same properties ? Is this impossible ?</strike>

What is the most *simple* scheme with projective invariance ?

Anything related to this subject, feel free to answer or ask any questions.

Thank's

Comment: Survey on subdivisions surfaces, 2012 Cashman : _Beyond Catmull–Clark? A survey of advances in subdivision surface methods_

Comment: Paper, 2009 Cashman : _NURBS with Extraordinary Points: High-degree, Non-uniform, Rational Subdivision Schemes_

Comment: If you're looking for the combination of NURBS and subdivision surfaces, then the paper *NURBS compatible subdivision surfaces* by Cashman might be what you're after.
If you're only looking for general information about CAGD, I can recommend *Curves and Surfaces for Computer Graphics* by Salomon. Tom Sederberg has a nice set of lecture notes on CAGD, freely available. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you.

This article was referenced by his later survey (cf. my first comment) and indeed it was very instructive.